# Best way to copy C++ buffer to Python

Tags: python, c++, c

When dealing with C extensions with Python, what is the best way to move data from a C++ array or `vector` into a `PyObject`/`PyList` so it can be returned to Python?

The method I am using right now seems a bit clunky. I am looping through each element and calling `Py_BuildValue` to append values to a `PyList`.

Is there something similar to `memcpy`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157409/stdvector-to-boostpythonlist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to construct a `PyObject` from each element prior to adding it to a sequence.

So you have to either add them one by one, or convert them all, then pass to a constructor from `PyObject[]`.

I guess the 2nd way is slightly faster since it doesn't have to adjust the sequence's member variables after each addition.

Answer (score 2):

If your vector holds homogenous numeric data, you're much better off creating an [`array.array`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/array.html) to transfer the values to Python.

Unlike a list, an array internally stores its values as a contiguous array of native C values, but otherwise provides a Pythonic list-like interface. It use minimizes memory footprint and enables you to actually use a single `memcpy` call to efficiently transfer the data. Here is an example:

```
PyObject *
vec_to_array(std::vector<double>& vec)
{
    static PyObject *single_array;
    if (!single_array) {
        PyObject *array_module = PyImport_ImportModule("array");
        if (!array_module)
            return NULL;
        PyObject *array_type = PyObject_GetAttrString(array_module, "array");
        Py_DECREF(array_module);
        if (!array_type)
            return NULL;
        // array.array('d', [0.0])
        single_array = PyObject_CallFunction(array_type, "c[d]", 'd', 0.0);
        Py_DECREF(array_type);
        if (!single_array)
            return NULL;
    }

    // extra-fast way to create an empty array of count elements:
    //   array = single_element_array * count
    PyObject *pysize = PyLong_FromSsize_t(vec.size());
    if (!pysize)
        return NULL;
    PyObject *array = PyNumber_Multiply(single_array, pysize);
    Py_DECREF(pysize);
    if (!array)
        return NULL;

    // now, obtain the address of the array's buffer
    PyObject *buffer_info = PyObject_CallMethod(array, "buffer_info", "");
    if (!buffer_info) {
        Py_DECREF(array);
        return NULL;
    }
    PyObject *pyaddr = PyTuple_GetItem(buffer_info, 0);
    void *addr = PyLong_AsVoidPtr(pyaddr);

    // and, finally, copy the data.
    if (vec.size())
        memcpy(addr, &vec[0], vec.size() * sizeof(double));

    return array;
}
```

Enhancing this with template specializations to support other primitive types is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 0):

If you can install Boost as a dependency, then you can take advantage of the `boost::python::list` class in order to make that conversion automatically. [Here are the docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/libs/python/doc/v2/list.html) and [here you can find an example of usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157409/stdvector-to-boostpythonlist) to convert a `std::vector` into a `python::list`.

Comment: Unfortunately boost is not an option