# How do I correctly access struct values and pass them to functions- boost::python

Tags: python, c++, struct, boost-python

I am struggeling to build a c++ python wrapper using boost. This might be a very basic question, but I failed to see the answer in the various existing tutorials.

[update: The fist part about how to access the struct data members was solved by xioxox post. The question which is still open is:
How do I write the wrapper for the vector inside the struct.]

[original post]
My C++ Part looks something like this:

```
struct Globals {
    AClass *a;
    BClass *b;
    int someInt = 5;
    bool check = FALSE;
    vector<unsigned short> someData
};

void func1(Globals* global)
{
    // ...
    // a propper inizialisation of the globals a and b Classes
    // ...
    global->check = global->a->returnSomething1(global->someInt);
    if(global->check)
    {
       global->someData = global->b->returnSomething2();
    }
    return;
}

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(demo)
{
  using namespace boost::python;
  class_<Globals>("Globals")
      .def_readonly("check", &Globals::check)
      .def_readwrite("someint", &Globals::someint);
      //someData to be done...

  def("func1", func1);

}
```

With Python I want to create a `Globals` Object, set the `someInt` inside of it and then pass it to `func1`. After the funcion is done I want to read the `check` value and if it is true, also the results saved in `someData` via python again.

When I import the libary in an IPython console it will give the following result

```
In [1]: import demo as d

In [2]: T = d.Globals

In [3]: T
Out[3]: demo.Globals 

In [4]: T.check
Out[4]: <property at 0xa2c72c8>  

In [5]: T.someInt
Out[5]: <property at 0xa2c7278> 

In [6]: T.someInt = 5

In [7]: d.func1(T)
Out[7]: <property at 0xa2c7278> 

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "<ipython-input-7-dc39ba21a63e>", line 1, in <module>
demo.func1(T)

ArgumentError: Python argument types in demo.func1(Boost.Python.class)
did not match C++ signature:
func1(struct Globals * __ptr64)
```

When I try to access the values I only see the C++ pointers. The struct however is changed into a `Boost.Python.class` as far as I understand it, I would have to get a pointer from this class and pass this as the `Globals*` input. How do I do that?

I also want to access the Vector data (`sapGlobal->images.data()`) in python, but I have no idea how to implement the wrapper for it.

Any help with that would be highly appreciated.

[update 2] The vector can be wrapped by including `#include <boost/python/suite/indexing/vector_indexing_suite.hpp>`
and adding the following line to the `BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE`

```
class_<vector<unsigned short>>("img")
        .def(vector_indexing_suite<vector<unsigned short>>());
```

As described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6157409/stdvector-to-boostpythonlist)

Comment: I'm not a boost-python user, but don't you actually need to instantiate the Globals class, i.e. T = d.Globals(), not T = d.Globals, or is Globals supposed to be some singleton?

Comment: Of cause, you are right, that's it! Thanks! What is still missing is the vector part...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that T is actually the class you have declared, and not an instance of the class. You need to say

```
T = d.Globals()
```

instead of

```
T = d.Globals
```