# Passing C++ STL containers in to Python?

Tags: python, c++

I have a C++ application with different STL containers (vector, unordered_map, queue etc).

I would like to embed Python within this C++ application and I would like to pass these containers through to the Python class.

I am aware Boost Python allows calling C++ from Python, but how do I call Python from C++ and pass these STL containers, so Python can process them?

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6158370/10077

Comment: [pybind11](http://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/master/advanced/embedding.html) can also be an option.

Comment: STL need to be converted to python data-structure before processing it, you can call from python to get c++ STL to python ds, then process it.